# How to create dynamic circles and links in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

js. If i use nodes in direct html means its displaying the diagram like

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="routeTestDisplay">
<svg width="500" height="250">
<g class="node" transform="translate(22.9523886259546,114.1646234701563)"><circle r="8" style="fill: rgb(49, 130, 189);"></circle><text x="12" dy=".35em" style="fill: rgb(49, 130, 189);">A</text></g>
<g class="node" transform="translate(110.00281475549397,114.1646234701563)"><circle r="8" style="fill: rgb(49, 130, 189);"></circle><text x="12" dy=".35em" style="fill: rgb(49, 130, 189);">B</text></g>
</svg>
</div>.
```

But am trying to draw this as dynamic like

```
var svg1 = $('<svg width=500 height=250></svg>');

    for(var x = 0; x < position.length; x++) {
        var obj = position[x];
        var g = '<g class="node" transform="translate('+obj.x+','+obj.y+')"><circle r="8" style="fill: rgb(49, 130, 189);"></circle><text x="12" dy=".35em" style="fill: rgb(49, 130, 189);">A</text></g>'
        svg1.append(g);
    }
    $('#routeTestDisplay').append(svg1);
```

The diagram is not displayed. I can see the html's when i do inspect element in firefox. Could you please anyone give me the solutions?

Comment: Youve just edited your question and asked a totally different one

Comment: Once a question has been answered you can't radically change it, it's not fair to the answerer.

Comment: @thisOneGuy I've rolled it back

Comment: @RobertLongson cheers :) Ive edited my answer to solve his updated questions as well as this :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would use D3 to show some nodes dynamically.

Firstly I'd have some data :

```
var data = [{
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  transformX: 22.9523886259546,
  transformY: 114.1646234701563
}, {
  x: 200,
  y: 200,
  transformX: 110.00281475549397,
  transformY: 114.1646234701563
}, {
  x: 300,
  y: 250,
  transformX: 22.9523886259546,
  transformY: 160.00281475549397
}]
```

Then I create my container  :

```
//html
<div id='container'>

</div>

//JS
var svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 400);
```

Then I would create the nodes from the data. Here you can set the x and y or in this case translate it later on from the data:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", 'red')
```

Now as I havent set x and y positions,just translate it according to the transformX and transformY in the data :

```
node.attr('transform', function(d) {
  console.log(d)
  return "translate(" + d.transformX + ',' + d.transformY + ')';
})
```

There you go, nodes on screen dependant on the data.

```js
var data = [{
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  transformX: 22.9523886259546,
  transformY: 114.1646234701563
}, {
  x: 200,
  y: 200,
  transformX: 110.00281475549397,
  transformY: 114.1646234701563
}, {
  x: 300,
  y: 250,
  transformX: 22.9523886259546,
  transformY: 160.00281475549397
}]


var svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 400);


var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", 'red')
  //.call(force.drag);

node.attr('transform', function(d) {
  console.log(d)
  return "translate(" + d.transformX + ',' + d.transformY + ')';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>

</div>
```

You could use your for loop to create the data which then gets passed to D3 to display the nodes.

For example :

```
var allData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < position.length; i++) {
  var pos = position[i];
  var thisData = {
    x: pos.x,
    y: pos.y
  }

  allData.push(thisData);

}
```

Then pass `allData` to D3 :) But instead of using `d.tranformX` for the translate you just use `d.x and d.y` like so :

```
node.attr('transform', function(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
})
```

EDIT

Here is a fiddle with your nodes and links in the correct place and different colours for links : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/ge6Lhfqr/

I colour them differently by using a colour scale : `var color = d3.scale.category10();`

Then iterate through this on each link :

```
.style("stroke", function(d,i){
   return color(i)
   })
```

Just to note, the links weren't displaying as the force layout wasn't run. What this does is when you have your links data like so :

```
var links = [{
  source: 0,
  target: 1
}, {
  source: 1,
  target: 2
}];
```

It goes through the data and finds the node it corresponds to. So instead of :

```
source:0;
```

It will then be :

```
source:node0 //which is the node object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. I will try your code.

Comment: Also I want to link the node with different line color. Could you please update that also?

Comment: Come on mate, youve asked one question, ive answered it, then you change the question so it looks like i dont understand what youre asking. And now your asking me to do something that you havent originally asked for ?

Comment: Once again thanks a lot. In future i will avoid these type of mistakes. Its working for me now.

Comment: no problem. Added another explanation at the bottom of my answer which will explain why the links werent showing.

Comment: @Suresh If you need an answer to a different question, ask a new question. You can always refer to this question in your new question if you feel it provides additional context.

Comment: Sure..I will follow your words